# Clean up on abort Tests run using MassTransit Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, specflow, masstransit, xunit.net

I have built of a suite of end-to-end tests for a group of event-driven services developed using MassTransit that communicates through azure service bus. The tests are developed using XUnit and SpecFlow and use an azure service bus. They run OK.

In my shared context that my specflow scenarios use,

```
private IBusControl? Bus { get; set; }

public async Task SetupBusAsync()
{
    Bus = MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(config =>
    {
         config.Host(<connection string goes here>);
         config.AutoDeleteOnIdle = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    });
    await Bus.StartAsync();
}

public async Task StopBusAsync()
{
    await Bus!.StopAsync();
}

public async Task SetupConsumer<TEventType>(<skipped>)
where TEventType : class
{
    var handle = Bus!.ConnectReceiveEndpoint(endpoint =>
                  endpoint.Handler<TEventType>(context =>
                  {
                     // Do something on the consumed message using a delegate
                  }));
    await handle.Ready;
}
```

I am facing an issue when these tests get aborted automatically or (almost always it is) manually for whatever reason, the current tests-run's service bus subscriptions don't get removed. I understand that the MassTransit bus is not stopped and ended abruptly in this case is the main reason. I tried setting `AutoDeleteOnIdle` and it doesn't help my case. Can anyone please suggest me a better approach to gracefully handle this scenario to remove the subscriptions that my tests create when the test-run is aborted?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MassTransit unit tests, I have a method called at fixture setup which deletes all topics and queues *prior* to running the test. That way, what's left after the test is available to review if needed. In a normal run, each test cleans up before it starts.

```cs
async Task CleanupNamespace()
{
    try
    {
        var managementClient = Configuration.GetManagementClient();

        var pageableTopics = managementClient.GetTopicsAsync();
        var topics = await pageableTopics.ToListAsync();
        while (topics.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var topic in topics)
                await managementClient.DeleteTopicAsync(topic.Name);

            topics = await managementClient.GetTopicsAsync().ToListAsync();
        }

        var pageableQueues = managementClient.GetQueuesAsync();
        var queues = await pageableQueues.ToListAsync();
        while (queues.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var queue in queues)
                await managementClient.DeleteQueueAsync(queue.Name);

            queues = await managementClient.GetQueuesAsync().ToListAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Also, Apologies for not being very clear.

I have a bunch of services subscribed to some events/topics and so I can't clear all subscriptions. What I do in my end-to-end tests is that I publish some event and wait for a service (that subscribes to that event type) to consume the event and publish an event which will be consumed my handler consumer to do some assertions and so on like a running scenario.

Also, thanks again for this brilliant framework.

Comment: Well, the above code is an example, you should be able to filter the results and only remove the subscriptions you want to remove, vs. all of them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I understand that ```AutoDeleteOnIdle``` of ```IServiceBusEndpointConfigurator``` applies to only queues. Do we have anything similar to ```AutoDeleteOnIdle``` of Subscription Properties of Azure Service Bus in MassTransit? This would help my case to remove stray subscriptions.

Comment: Azure Service Bus does not honor AutoDeleteOnIdle for subscriptions that forward to a queue, which is why `RemoveSubscriptions` exists.

Comment: Sorry, one last question - Is there an option to Connect Subscription Endpoint on IBusControl somewhat along the lines of ConnectReceiveEndpoint? Mainly because SubscriptionEndpoint enables me to set autodeleteonidle for subscriptions. Thank you, again!

Comment: You can use `ISubscriptionEndpointConnector` from the container.

Comment: Many thanks, again. Maybe my code sample was not too clear. Once the bus is started, consumers for a number of event types are set up using my generic ```SetupConsumer``` method that takes a func or action for what I want to do with the consumed message. So I am not sure if container can help my case. I will look for some different approach instead of using IBusControl maybe. Thank you. I appreciate your help so far.